# VBA Incremental character spacing

Tags: vba, fonts, powerpoint

I have this code to condense text to 0.2 but would like to have it incremental. So each time I run the code the text condense by 0.2.
Does anyone know what I need to add to my code?

```
Sub CondenseText()

    On Error GoTo Catch

    Dim o As Shape, b As Boolean
    Set o = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
    If Not o Is Nothing Then
        With o
            .TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Spacing = -0.2
        End With
    End If
    Exit Sub
Catch:
    If Err.Number = -2147188160 Then MsgBox CG_NOTHING_SELECTED
End Sub
```

Comment: `.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Spacing = .TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Spacing - 0.2`

Comment: You are a vba wizard! Thank you!